# Какой аргумент просит функция в классе Python: "TaskNumber1() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'"

Tags: python, python-3.x

Сам код:

```
class TasksForMath:        
    def TaskNumber1(self):
        print("\nПоезд ехал со скоростью 110 км/ч. С такой же скоростью он ехал 6 часов.\nКакое расстояние преодолел поезд за эти 6 часов?")


while True:
    now_execute_number = 1
    print(f"Задача номер {now_execute_number}")
    TasksForMath.TaskNumber1()
```

А ошибка:

```
File "C:\Users\FleshStinger\Desktop\Задачи.py", line 10, in <module>
TasksForMath.TaskNumber1()
TypeError: TaskNumber1() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Что я хотел сделать: я хочу чтобы у меня вызвалась функция из класса **TasksForMath** "*TaskNumber1()*",
но он просит аргумент. Я добавил аргумент **self** но выдаёт ошибку. Что делать?

Comment: Функции и методы описывайте в змеиной нотации, как это было в переменной `now_execute_number`. В ответе показал как

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Сначала вы определитесь: статичный метод или метод объекта?

---

### Статичный

Статичный может вызываться самим типом (или объектами типам), как тут:

```
TasksForMath.task_number_1()
```

У статичных методов нет аргумента `self` и им нужно указывать декоратор `@staticmethod`:

```
class TasksForMath:
    @staticmethod
    def task_number_1():
        ...
```

---

### Метод объекта

Метод объекта может вызываться исключительно объектами:

```
tasks = TasksForMath()
tasks.task_number_1()
```

Для этих методов обязателен аргумент `self`:

```
class TasksForMath:
    def task_number_1(self):
        ...
```

---

### Метод класса

Метод класса очень похож на статичный метод: может вызываться самим типом (или объектами типам), как тут:

```
TasksForMath.task_number_1()
```

Но есть одна фишка -- обязательная передача аргумента `cls` в методы класса и указание декоратора `@classmethod`:

```
class TasksForMath:
    @classmethod
    def task_number_1(cls):
        ...
```

Это позволит в методах класса при обращении с `cls` вызывать поля и методы класса

Answer (score 2):

Т.к. `TaskNumber1` не является `classmethod`, то для его вызова необходимо создать объект класса, в котором определён этот метод.

Просто добавив две круглые скобки в ваш фрагмент кода, мы получаем приемлемый результат:

```py
class TasksForMath:        
    def TaskNumber1(self):
        print("\nПоезд ехал со скоростью 110 км/ч. С такой же скоростью он ехал 6 часов.\nКакое расстояние преодолел поезд за эти 6 часов?")


while True:
    now_execute_number = 1
    print(f"Задача номер {now_execute_number}")
    TasksForMath().TaskNumber1()
```

Обратите внимание на то, что цикл бесконечен.

Если не хотите создавать экземпляр класса, то воспользуйтесь декоратором `@classmethod`:

```py
class TasksForMath: 

    @classmethod   
    def TaskNumber1(cls):
        print("\nПоезд ехал со скоростью 110 км/ч. С такой же скоростью он ехал 6 часов.\nКакое расстояние преодолел поезд за эти 6 часов?")


while True:
    now_execute_number = 1
    print(f"Задача номер {now_execute_number}")
    TasksForMath().TaskNumber1()
```

Comment: Мне не нужен экземпляр этого класса. Зачем нужен этот декоратор? Чтобы сделать его статичным и вызывать его не создавая экземпляр? Просто раньше C# изучал

Comment: Декоратор `@classmethod` создан для того, чтобы вызвать определённый метод, заключенный в теле класса без создания экземпляра самого класса. Очень часто используется в качестве альтернативных конструкторов.

Answer (score -2):

Просто уберите `self` из аргументов функции, если не хотите, чтобы это был метод экземпляра класса, а хотите, чтобы это был статический метод, который можно вызывать, используя название класса:

```
class TasksForMath:        
    def TaskNumber1():
        print("\nПоезд ехал со скоростью 110 км/ч. С такой же скоростью он ехал 6 часов.\nКакое расстояние преодолел поезд за эти 6 часов?")

now_execute_number = 1
print(f"Задача номер {now_execute_number}")
TasksForMath.TaskNumber1()
```

Цикл я убрал, потому что он бесконечный.
Вывод:

```
Задача номер 1

Поезд ехал со скоростью 110 км/ч. С такой же скоростью он ехал 6 часов.
Какое расстояние преодолел поезд за эти 6 часов?
```